# Add custom links like functionality

Tags: menus, metabox

I want same functionality like WordPress provide for custom links but additionally I want to add some class to those links by default that is added by this feature (Other websites).

[image]

I have tried to add it with **add_meta_box** but it is not working.

Comment: You can enable class option for menu items from "Screen Options" at top right corner.

Comment: @Bhupen Yes you're right but I want it by-default.